# Setting up Octave with gnuplot support in Emacs

Tags: windows-7, emacs, gnuplot, octave

I added the Octave binary directory containing octave and gnuplot executables to the PATH in Windows 7. This has allowed me to run inferior-octave mode in Emacs.  However, I cannot display graphs like I can with the commandline version.  No errors show up; the graphs just don't appear anywhere.  How can I fix this?

Edit:  GNU Plot wont run in Emacs Calc either, although several GNU Plot related buffers are created.  But there are no errors as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot;
```

at the Octave console.

I had the same problem and that worked for me.